# How to add Word document content into PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, aspose-slides

I want to insert Word document parts into PowerPoint presentation.
For now I know 3 ways to do this.

1. COM Interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint). I can add whole
   Word document as OLE Object into presentation. Document is embedded
   in PP presentation. Drawbacks: COM is slow. PP presentation file
   size might increase drastically because of embedded Word documents,
   but in my case it won’t be a problem.
2. Simulate what COM is doing in XML by hand (using Office Open XML).
   When a document is added as OLE object then in (PP presentation
   file)/ppt/slides/slide{slide_number}.xml there is created "< p:oleObj
   …>" tag referencing embedded document. This tag is inside
   "< mc:AlternateContent …>" which contains this "< p:oleObj ...>" and
   "< mc:Fallback>" which contains reference to a thumbnail generated
   for document. I couldn’t delete this thumbnail so PP could generate
   it on opening for inserted document. Do you know **how can I force it
   to be generated again on document opening (or inserting without
   COM)?**
3. Aspose.Slides (for .NET) or something similar.

Could you help me with second case? Or am I forced to use Aspose.Slides (or similar) if I want it to work reasonably fast?

Comment: In principle, you can use whatever image you like (ie instead of the thumbnail).  But you need an image, and I don't think it'll be replaced when you open the pptx in Powerpoint.  It may be altered when you OLE activate the object (ie by clicking on it).

Comment: @JasonPlutext I could use any image, but in this case I should generate it for content I'm about to insert. This might be more work. I'm wondering if I can automate whole process of inserting document into PP without COM.